# Elixir - String Split problem when I see the result in console

Tags: split, elixir

I am new with Elixir and I'm trying to build a given float currency value in parameter of a function and transform into an object with {integer: , decimal}
When I transform the float value into string ad split it .. the return values are weird

I call the function via iex, but instead my split function returns ["4", "50"], it returned 450..

So, I tried to print the foo bar example and it returned foobar instead ["foo", "bar"]

Here is the code:

```
def amountFormatter(amount) do
    stringAmount = Float.to_string(amount)
    splittedAmount = String.split(stringAmount, ".")
    IO.puts(String.split("foo bar", " "))
    integer = Enum.at(splittedAmount, 0)
    decimal = Enum.at(splittedAmount, 1) || 0
    amountFormatted = %{
      integer: Float.parse(integer),
      decimal: Float.parse(decimal)
    }
    amountFormatted
  end
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Rafael, welcome to Stackexchange and to Elixir!  =)  You've got a fun journey ahead of you.  It's a little easier to help you if you copy and paste output from your terminal rather than including a screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

When you pass a list to `IO.puts/2`, the list is treated as [chardata](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#module-chardata). Essentially it concatenates everything in the list.

```rb
iex> IO.puts(["foo", "bar"])
foobar # printed
:ok # returned
```

To inspect a value when running code, you're better off using `IO.inspect/2`:

```rb
iex> IO.inspect(["foo", "bar"])
["foo", "bar"] # printed
["foo", "bar"] # returned
```